# Category tree in AngularJS don´t display correctly with use of recursive template

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using AngularJs and Bootstrap and I want to show in grouped form according to the category the different varieties of wines, this I want to do in the form of thumbnails, for this I use the bootstrap classes "thumbnail" and inside "caption", to show data of the wine . The problem I'm having is that I do not know because it shows me an empty thumbnail after the category name.
I cant make me show separate groups varietals and not after the last previous varietal wine.

My HTML:

```
<div class="container" ng-app="app" ng-controller='ctrl'>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="categoryTree">

        <h3>{{ category.category_name }}</h3>

        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img ng-src="{{ category.photo }}">
            <div class="caption">
                <h3>{{ category.name }}</h3>
                <h4>{{ category.bodega }}</h4>
                <p>{{ category.variedad }}</p>
                <p>{{ category.price | currency }}</p>  
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div ng-if="category.subcategories">

            <div ng-repeat="category in category.subcategories" ng-include="'categoryTree'">           
            </div>

        </div>

    </script>



    <div ng-repeat="category in categories" ng-include="'categoryTree'"></div>

</div>
```

My JS:

```
angular.module("app", []).
controller("ctrl", ['$scope', function ($scope) {       
    $scope.categories =[
    {    
    "category_name":"Tintos",
    "subcategories":
    [
       {
          "id": 1,
          "parentId": 1,
          "name": "El Enemigo",
          "variedad": "Cabernet Sauvignon",
          "bodega": "Catena Zapata",
          "price":"13.75",
          "photo":"http://www.sietespirits.com/product_images/g/598/El_enemigo_Malbec__72225_zoom.jpg?id=1"
        }, 
        {
          "id": 2,
          "parentId": 1,
          "name": "Altas Cumbres",
          "variedad": "Malbec",
          "bodega": "Lagarde",
          "price":"82",
          "photo":"http://www.lagarde.com.ar/uploads/wines/altascumbres.png"
        }
    ]
    },
    {
    "category_name":"Blancos",
    "subcategories":[{
          "id": 5,
          "name": "El Zorzal",
          "variedad": "Chardonnay",
          "bodega": "Zorzal",
          "price":"13.75",
          "photo":"http://tonelprivado.vteximg.com.br/arquivos/ids/163090-1000-1000/Finca-El-Zorzal-.-Chardonnay-.-750-ml.300424.jpg"
    }]
  }

]

}
])
```

I leave you a fiddle [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/progemo/zgtgqw97/2/)

Thank you very much for reading me.

Comment: Any particular reason to use `ng-include`? Can do without it?

Comment: Hi @Sajal the reason to use nginclude is according to the article [AngularJS recursive templates](http://benfoster.io/blog/angularjs-recursive-templates) you must use it to render the template that is between the script tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursive templates work well when the sub categories have the same property names as the parent category so as to create a generic template. Data structure for parent and child is different here.

Anyhow, sub category has a property as `id` which parent does not, you could conditional check for it and hide the default thumbnail.

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4" ng-if="category.id">
  <div class="thumbnail">
     .....
  </div>
</div>
```

[Working Demo with ng-include](https://jsfiddle.net/xdLpudsy/2/)

If the data structure is what you have that is object with different property names, I'd suggest to go with nested `ng-repeat` to create an additional scope for sub categories.

In future, if you decide to add an `id` property for the parent category, the above fiddle won't work as expected. See the below fiddle.

[Working demo with nested ng-repeat](https://jsfiddle.net/o8m0bnfn/2/)

Comment: Thank you very much @Sajal! I add  `<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4" ng-if="category.name"> ` instead of the id that you use, but just as your explanation cleared me doubts about the recursive templates. :-)